# How to return Empty Response in chatbot python-flask?

Tags: python, chatterbot

How can I get empty response when I search for some questions which are not available?

If the question is available it should return correct response.

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot

from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
chatterbot = ChatBot("Training Example")
chatterbot.set_trainer(ListTrainer)

chatterbot.train([
    "Hi there!",
    "Hello",
])

chatterbot.train([
    "Greetings!",
    "Hello",
])

chatbot.train(["Greetings!","Hello",])

chatbot.train(["How are you?","I am good.","That is good to 
hear.","Thank you","You are welcome.",])

while True:

try:

  a = input("question please..? ")

  response = chatterbot.get_response(a)

  print(response)

except (KeyboardInterrupt,SystemExit):

  print("your loop has been closed: ")

  break
```

Answer (score 1):

- [LowConfidenceAdapter](https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/logic/index.html?highlight=LowConfidenceAdapter#low-confidence-response-adapter) can be used to return a default response if a response can not be determined with a high amount of confidence.
- Set a `threshold` value as minimum confidence score of the response. If the confidence is less than this `threshold` value, it will return the default response.

Updated code using `LowConfidenceAdapter`:

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot

from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
chatbot = ChatBot("Training Example",
                  logic_adapters=[
                    {
                        'import_path': 'chatterbot.logic.BestMatch'
                    },
                    {
                        'import_path': 'chatterbot.logic.LowConfidenceAdapter',
                        'threshold': 0.65,
                        'default_response': 'I am sorry, but I do not understand.'
                    }
                ])

chatbot.set_trainer(ListTrainer)

chatbot.train([
    "Hi there!",
    "Hello"])

chatbot.train([
    "Hello",
    "Hey!"])

chatbot.train([
    "How are you?",
    "I am good."])
chatbot.train([    
    "That is good to hear.",
    "Thank you",
    "You are welcome."])
chatbot.train([
    "Sure, I'd like to book a flight to Iceland.",
    "Your flight has been booked."])

while True:
    try:
        a = input("Question please..? ")
        response = chatbot.get_response(a)
        print(response)
    except (KeyboardInterrupt,SystemExit):
        print("\nYour loop has been closed.")
        break
```

Output:

[image: chatterbot example]

Comment: @kiran, if the answer is helpful, please accept and upvote it. :)

Comment: i had another question regarding how to get multiple responses when we request a question in chatbot?

Comment: Please feel free to create another question with question details. It is not preferred in Stackoverflow to ask and answer multiple questions in a single query :).